# What did Spock want Bones to "Remember"?

Tags: star-trek

In the movie Star Trek: Wrath of Khan, what did Spock mean when he mind melded with McCoy and he told him to "remember"?

Comment: The answer to this might be a spoiler for *Star Trek III* if you haven’t yet seen it. Your question is answered in the sequel.

Comment: @Todd mind you - ST3 was 35 years ago :)

Comment: @JonClements And *Star Trek II* is even older, yet here we have someone who either doesn’t know or doesn’t remember the answer to this question, and I still remember the answer after all this time because it’s significant. GalacticCrimminal might prefer to find out the old fashioned way if they are planning to watch the sequel and haven’t already done so.

Comment: His PIN number so that he could delete his browser history

Comment: The answer is, everything. Or is even that too much of a spoiler?

Comment: Valorum  stop commenting and start writing screenplays! Honestly,  that just made my day!

Answer (score 5):

As hinted at in the comments, [Star Trek II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek_II:_The_Wrath_of_Khan) and [Star Trek III](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek_III:_The_Search_for_Spock) (and also [Star Trek IV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek_IV:_The_Voyage_Home)) form a mini-series of movies with a single broad narrative arc.

The basic plot of ST.III is to go over to the Genesis Planet and find Spock's body, return it to Vulcan and let the Vulcans do whatever magic it is they do to dead people. Only, in stead of Spock's body, they discover a young & horny "regenerated" Spock, first as a child, but he rapidly grows into a teen ager and falls for Lt. Saavik.

Eventually, the rapidly maturing Spock grows up to his approximate age at the time of death and the crew travel to Vulcan. What Spock wanted McCoy to "remember", apparently, was his *catra* or soul. Vulcan magic is such that they can reintroduce the *catra* into the now regenereated body of Spock.

And they lived happily ever after, until they have to go find some whales.

Comment: Idle thought: out-of-universe, do we have any evidence that this was what the makers of II intended at the time? Did they already have the idea for the plot of III?

Comment: @DanielRoseman See: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/110310/how-much-of-the-plot-of-the-search-for-spock-was-determined-when-the-wrath-of-kh?rq=1